# Add html elements to file containted in the includes / abstracts folder when using woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Can't find a proper solution how to override woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-payment-gateway.php file.
I just need to add some html elements to this part of code:

```
$default_fields = array(
        'card-number-field' => '<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-number">' . __( 'Card Number', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input id="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-number" class="input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-number" type="text" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••" name="' . ( $args['fields_have_names'] ? $this->id . '-card-number' : '' ) . '" />
        </p>',
        'card-expiry-field' => '<p class="form-row form-row-first">
            <label for="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-expiry">' . __( 'Expiration Date', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input id="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-expiry" class="input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-expiry" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="' . __( 'MM / YY', 'woocommerce' ) . '" name="' . ( $args['fields_have_names'] ? $this->id . '-card-expiry' : '' ) . '" />
        </p>',
        'card-cvc-field' => '<p class="form-row form-row-last">
            <label for="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-cvc">' . __( 'Security Code', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input id="' . esc_attr( $this->id ) . '-card-cvc" class="input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-cvc" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="' . __( 'CVC', 'woocommerce' ) . '" name="' . ( $args['fields_have_names'] ? $this->id . '-card-cvc' : '' ) . '" />
        </p>'
    );
```

I have tried solutions from this thread [Override woocomerce files from includes folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573928/override-woocomerce-files-from-includes-folder) but no luck.
Can somebody help with solution. Thanks

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm trying to figure it out now.