# Wordpress Woocommerce plugin mail triggering

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Mail not sending when status changed from processing to on-hold and processing to failed.
Kindly tell me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Even that kind of questions (directly asking the need without any research or any part of code) are not welcomed here, I want to help you about that by giving the basic idea.

In the file "**wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php**", search for the "**public static function init_transactional_emails()**" and check "**$email_actions**" array there.

```
$email_actions = apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_email_actions', array(
                'woocommerce_low_stock',
                'woocommerce_no_stock',
                'woocommerce_product_on_backorder',
                'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing',
                'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed',
                'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_cancelled',
                'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_failed',
                'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold',
                'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing',
                'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed',
                'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_on-hold',
                'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_processing',
                'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_cancelled',
                'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_failed',
                'woocommerce_order_status_completed',
                'woocommerce_order_fully_refunded',
                'woocommerce_order_partially_refunded',
                'woocommerce_new_customer_note',
                'woocommerce_created_customer',
            )
        );
```

Since after every update of Woocommerce plugin any changes you made on those files **will be gone**, you need to add your email trigger for status changes you mentioned by **either using a hook or overriding the files using your child theme**.

About your request, for "from processing to on-hold" you need to add:

```
'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_on-hold',
```

About overriding a file (or function) from includes folder of Woocommerce you may check this post: [Override woocommerce files from includes folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573928/override-woocommerce-files-from-includes-folder)

I hope this will help you to solve it. Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks. Only those change is enough?

Comment: You are welcome, write me back via my social accounts if you cannot do it.